# Random Forest - Caret - Time Series

Tags: r, random-forest, forecasting, predict, r-caret

I have a time series (apple stock prices -closing prices- turn into a data frame to fit a random forest using caret. I lagged on 1 day, 2 days and 6 days. I want to predict the next 2 days. Two step ahead forecast. But `caret`uses the `predict`function that does not allow the argument `h`as the `forecast`function. And i have seen that some people try to put the argument `n.ahead` but is not working for me. Any advice? See the code

```
df<-data.frame(APPL)
df$f1<-lag(df$APPL,1)
df$f2=lag(df$APPL,2)
df$f3=lag(df$APPL,6)

# change column names

colnames(df)<-c("price", "price_1", "price_2", "price_6")

# remove rows (days) with NA.
df<-df[complete.cases(df),]

fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 1,
  classProbs = FALSE,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  preProcOptions=list(thresh = 0.95, na.remove = TRUE, verbose = TRUE))

set.seed(1234)

rf_grid= expand.grid(mtry = c(1:3))

fit <- train(price~.,
                 data=df,
                 method="rf",
                 preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                 tuneGrid = rf_grid,
                 trControl=fitControl,
                 ntree = 200,
                 metric="RMSE")


nextday <- predict(fit,`WHAT GOES HERE?`)
```

If i put just `predict(fit)`uses as `newdata`the whole dataset. Which i think is wrong. The other thing i was thinking about is to do a loop. Predict for 1 step ahead, because i have the data of 1,2 and 6 days ago. And the fill for the 2 step ahead forecast the 1 day ago "cell" with the forecast i did before.

Comment: First advice, you need to add a reproducible example otherwise we can't test code to help. Second advice, your script would result in an error anyway as you haven't closed the double quotation mark at the `colnames` function line. Third advice, the `predict.randomForest` function has no `n.ahead` argument. Fourth advice, I don't see why a machine learning algorithm should behave like forecast which is an econometric algorithm for time series..

Comment: Amazing feedback @LyzandeR Thanks you!

Comment: ... so timeseries 'rolling window' and RF works fine for time series forecasting. But you can only choose one target pr model.fit. Simply inputting features as day -1,-2 and -6 is not good enough to build a useful model. It will be predictive, but in a senseless way as stocks are not stationary. "I predict apple price tomorrow is gonna be something close of today, and so on...". You need to transform data to log dif or relative change. What you want to know is if the stock has an increased chance to rise tomorrow, and you wan't to know this with a higher certainty than other trading agents.

Comment: @Soren that is true. I was thinking to bring external features. But they will be available only for the "training" and not for the "test" (or predictive). Unless of course i use predictive values for them also. Imagine, GDP growth, or something like that. I was thinking auto-regressive, because I was able to have a full panel of variables. But you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you can't pass other options to the underlying predict method. There is a [proposed change](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/187) that might enable this though.

In your case, you should give the predict function a data frame that has the appropriate predictors for the next few observations.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1:: colnames(df)<-c("price","price_1","price_2","price_6") ;; "after price6
#2:: Predict{stats} is a generic function for predictions from the results of various model fitting functions

::predict(model object , dataframe)
we have 3 cases here for dataframe ::
case 1 :: train data::on which model is fitted :: Insample prediction
case 2 :: test data::Out of sample prediction
case 3 :: forecasted  data :: forecasted values of the independent variables : we get the forecasted values of the dependent variable according to the model

The column names in case 2 & 3 should be same as column names of the train data
```

Comment: This post is really hard to read. Please could you reformat it?

Comment: hope this may help